# Script triggers

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function, macro-recorder

I have been having problems with running out of my quota using Google Sheets and an ImportJSON function as the ImportJSON was running everytime the sheet refreshes.

To get around this, I recorded 3 separate macros. The first places the ImportJSON formula into a cell:

```
function ApplyImportJSON() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=ImportJSON("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
};
```

The second, then copy & pastes values from that sheet into a second sheet in the workbook:`

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:FG1').activate();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet22'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'JSON BSS\'!A1:FG1000').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

'Then the third, removes the ImportJSON formula:`

```
function DeleteImportJSON() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

I've been trying to set up each to run in sync by setting up triggers for each but it just takes one to fall out of sync and it then doesn't do what I want. I have a very limited knowledge of scripts but I'm sure there must be a way (for someone smarter than me!) to combine all three into one script that runs with a 60 second delay between each part that I can then use just one trigger to run the script every 15 minutes?

I'm pretty sure this is a very longwinded way of getting it to do what I'd like it to do but I can't seem to find a way of getting the original ImportJSON script to just refresh every 10 minutes.`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that using a trigger to add a custom function every 10 minutes is a good idea, instead, use the trigger to execute the IMPORTJSON function and write the data directly to the required sheet.

Example:

```
function every10minutes(){
  const data = ImportJSON("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/");
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet22');
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, it is only returning the first 5 rows of the sheet. Is there anyway to increase this too 1000? It is also returning the following error: 

'Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 150 but the range has 161.'

Comment: @RobChetty The code in my answer is working fine for me. Double check that there isn't any typo on your copy. If you still have problems, I suggest you to start from scratch (create a new spreadsheet, add a sheet and name it `Sheet22`, add the IMPORTJSON code, then the above function, then create the time-drive trigger calling the `every10minutes` function).

Comment: I've tried on a fresh sheet and it is still returning just the first 5 rows. I'm not sure if there's something in the original IMPORTJSON script that is stopping it from working correctly? Link to the sheet is here if you'd like to see? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RC-ujVN22_DMhwjlLRVfKvblm1v9hSP3kQi-tg2yiDw/

Comment: @RobChetty I made a copy of your spreadsheet... it works fine for me.

Comment: I've changed the IMPORTJSON script and now it returns all of the rows for some columns and there are other columns it is not returning everything.

Comment: @RobChetty I suggest you to post a new question providing enough details about what is the result that you expect.